# Cannot build github.com/jonpchin/gochess - "working directory is not part of a module"

Tags: windows, go

I unwrapped the project and from that project i did go get. Then I received the following errors.

```
C:\Users\Downloads\gochess-master>go install main.go
main.go:14:2: no required module provides package github.com/dchest/captcha: working directory is not part of a module 
main.go:15:2: no required module provides package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: working directory is not part of a module 
main.go:17:2: no required module provides package github.com/jonpchin/gochess/goforum: working directory is not part of a module 
main.go:18:2: no required module provides package github.com/jonpchin/gochess/gostuff: working directory is not part of a module 
main.go:20:2: no required module provides package golang.org/x/net/websocket: working directory is not part of a module
```

Then I went and tried doing go get each of the packages. I try doing the `go install main.go` and got same error.

then I tried including the repo inside `$GOPATH/src/github.com/jonpchin/gochess` and tried doing go get from there. I got the same errors.

Answer (score 3):

`github.com/jonpchin/gochess` is a couple of years old and has not been updated to use [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules). I suspect you are using [Go 1.16](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16) under which "Module-aware mode is enabled by default, regardless of whether a go.mod file is present in the current working directory or a parent directory". There are a few ways to address this but given that [there is a plan to](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes) "drop support for GOPATH mode in Go 1.17" the simplest approach might be to download the code and setup modules yourself. The following process works for me (well I get prompted for a mysql password):

```
git clone https://github.com/jonpchin/gochess
cd gochess
go mod init github.com/jonpchin/gochess
go get
go build
.\gochess.exe
```

Comment: Would it be hard to upgrade it to the idiomatic in 1.16 or 1.17. Meaning how hard or how is that I can setup modules myself.

Comment: Running `go mod init github.com/jonpchin/gochess` (create the module) and `go get` (determine and retrieve dependencies) is really all that is needed  (the result is two files 'go.mod' and `go.sum`; adding those to the project is all that is neccessary).